# Exercicio Vetores, estou encalhado

Tags: c, vector

Pretende-se elaborar um programa que peça números inteiros ao utilizador e que os guarde num vetor, este procedimento repete-se até que o utilizador digite o valor zero.

No final o programa deverá mostrar todos os valores que o utilizador introduziu.
Deverá ainda, considerar os seguintes pressupostos: - Guarda no vetor, apenas os valores no intervalo [100, 500]; - O vetor tem uma capacidade máxima de 15 elementos; - Quando a capacidade chega ao limite deverá avisar o utilizador.

Deverá obrigatoriamente desenvolver os seguintes subprogramas: - Uma função com o protótipo, `int lerVectorDeInteiros(int tabelaInteiros[], int nElementos)`, que vai tratar da recolha dos números inteiros, guardar esses valores no vetor , e considerar todos os pressupostos anteriores.
No final a função deverá devolver a quantidade de elementos inseridos no vetor. - Um procedimento com o seguinte protótipo, `void mostrarTabelaInteiros(int tabelaInteiros[], int nElementos)` , que vai mostrar no ecrã apenas os valores introduzidos pelo utilizador.

Código feito até o momento:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 15

int lerVectorDeInteiros(int *);

int main ()
{
    int vetor[MAX];
    int quantidadeElementos = 0;

    quantidadeElementos =lerVectorDeInteiros(vetor);
    printf("A quantidade de elementos que foram inseridos no vetor sao %d", quantidadeElementos);

    return 0;
}

int lerVectorDeInteiros ( int vetor[MAX] )
{
    int i;
    int temp = 0;
    int contador = 0;

    for ( i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
    {
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        if(temp > 99 && temp < 501)
        {
            vetor[i] = temp;
            contador++;
        }
    }

    return contador;
}
```

Comment: O que você já fez? Qual é sua dúvida?

Comment: Boa tarde Pablo, nada, estou a olhar para o problema porque eu nem entendo por onde começar

Comment: #define MAX 15

int lerVectorDeInteiros(int *);

int main()
{
    int vetor[MAX];
    int quantidadeElementos = 0;

    quantidadeElementos =lerVectorDeInteiros(vetor);
    printf("A quantidade de elementos que foram inseridos no vetor sao %d", quantidadeElementos);

    return 0;
}

int lerVectorDeInteiros(int vetor[MAX]){
    int i;
    int temp = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        if(temp > 99 && temp < 501){
            vetor[i] = temp;
            contador++;
        }
    }
    return contador;
}

Comment: Esse código é que que já elaborou para tentar resolver o problema ? Se sim adicione-o à pergunta

Comment: Eu sou novo aqui, como é que faço isso?

Comment: Eu votei para fechar a pergunta pois você apenas colou aqui o enunciado do trabalho, e nem se dignou a colocar uma palavra de texto sua ou a mostrar o que já fez. Lembre-se que a comunidade StackOverflow PT não é um serviço gratuito de resolução de trabalhos de faculdade.

Comment: Isac eu compreendo e percebo, desculpe, sou novo aqui. Obrigado! :D

Comment: cara, você tem que adicionar seu código e também tem que nos especificar qual sua duvida, sugiro que edite a pergunta e adicione a sua duvida, para adicionar um código, basta copia-lo da IDE usada, depois selecione ele inteiro e clique no botão {}, okay ;)

Comment: `Exercicio Vetores, estou encalhado` -> [você não conseguirá resolver isso com programação](https://xkcd.com/55/).

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro erro, você ta fazendo a leitura da variável "temp" e está gerando número aleatórios com isso, e esse não é o objetivo. Você tem que fazer a leitura do usuário, enquanto for != 0 você vai gerar números.

Segundo, você ao gerar um número, deve verificar se este mesmo já existe dentro do vetor, se já tiver você gera outro, senão você insere na próxima posição disponível.

Dica: use uma variável para fazer a leitura do usuário e outra para fazer a contagem dos números. Acho que com essa ajuda já consegue resolver seu problema.